# Do I need removeEventListener if I delete the object that I added it to?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I have a function that dynamically generates `li`s and then attached `addEventListener` that allows users to delete the row.  Do I need to `removeEventListener` even if delete the row already?

```
function li (){
  var li = document.createElement('li'), 
      that = this;

  li.addEventListener('click', function(){
     that.delete(li);
  }
}
```

On the side note, I am using an anonymous function to pass `li` into the function. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to call `removeEventListener`.

Use the below to remove self on click self.

```
li.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}​);​
```